# SQLAlchemy primaryjoin returns emtpy object for one-to-many relation

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, one-to-many

I have tables defined as:

```
class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'
    CarID = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    CarDetails = relationship(
          "CarDetails", 
          back_populates="Car", 
          primaryjoin="and_(CarDetails.CarID == Car.CarID, CarDetails.CarNumber == 1)",
        )
    CustomCarDetails = relationship(
              "CarDetails", back_populates="Car", uselist=True)

class CarDetails(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'car_details'
    ID = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    CarNumber = Column('car_number', Integer, default=1)
    CarID = Column('table_id', Integer, ForeignKey(
        'tables.id'), nullable=False)
    Car = relationship("Car", back_populates="CustomCarDetails")
```

*Car: CarDetails* follows *1-to-many* relation. In *CarDetails* column (in Car), I want to populate entries with *CarNumber=1* for the respective Car. With the above definition, I get empty object. I have referred [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) also. What am I missing here ?

When I have it defined as follows, CarDetails returns a random entry from CarDetails(may return the record with *CarNumber != 1*), whereas I only want entry corresponding to *CarNumber=1*:

```
CarDetails = relationship(
                "CarDetails", 
                back_populates="Car", 
                uselist=False)
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding *uselist=False* worked here:

```
CarDetails = relationship(
      "CarDetails", 
      back_populates="Car", 
      primaryjoin="and_(CarDetails.CarID == Car.CarID, CarDetails.CarNumber == 1)",
      uselist=False
    )
```

I couldn't find this in the documentation!!